# How to maintain JavaScript performance while making an Ajax request at mousemove event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$( document ).bind( 'mousemove', function ( e )
{
    if ( e.pageY > $( document ).height() - 400 )
    {
        $.ajax( {
            url: '/Tweet/GetFiveUserTweets',
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,  // preventing a lot of asynchronous requests            
            success: function ( result )
            {
                // result
            }
        } );
    }
} );
```

‘async:false’ hangs the browser until request completes and that’s not good.

and when remove '`async:false'`, dozen of simultaneous request made because **mousemove** event....

I don’t want to hang the browser.

I just want a single asynchronous Ajax request at a time.

Can anyone let me know how to do a better coding for this situation?

Edit:

Actually when user scroll down at bottom, I want to get five next records and append them at bottom. www.twitter.com do this with tweets....

what's about:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
 if (nearBottomOfPage()) {
   // load things here ...
 }
});
```

I think it's better than mousemove...am I right?

Comment: Do not use `async: false`. Problem solved :) What do you need it for anyway?

Comment: why do you want to use the mousemove event in this case at all? Isn't there a 'less-occuring' event to start with to deal with the trigger?

Comment: then dozen of simultaneous requests...what to do with them...I just need a single request at a time....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make async true.

To avoid multiple simultaneous requests, before starting a request, check a variable, for example `if(!active_check) {...}` and then set that variable when you start, `active_check=true`. When the request completes, set the variable to false/null again.

```
if(!active_check) {
  active_check=true;
  //do request with callback to change active check when done
}
```

or using your code...

```
$( document ).bind( 'mousemove', function ( e )
{
    if ( (e.pageY > $( document ).height() - 400) && !active_check)
    {
        active_check = true;
        $.ajax( {
            url: '/Tweet/GetFiveUserTweets',
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,  
            success: function ( result )
            {
                active_check = false;
            }
        } );
    }
} );
```

That said, the mousemove event fires extremely frequently. You'll want to use something else, if you can.

Comment: what else event you prefer @Jonathan (other than mousemove)...can you let me know please...

Comment: @Muaz Khan Without using a in-flight guard, NO repeating event is "safe".

Comment: @Muaz: Have you looked into using Infinte Scroll (http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/)?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a really *bad* idea to fire request on a *mousemove* event.

As you mentioned correctly, this will cause dozens of request, more than any average server will take/accept and are useless anyway in this case. You should reconsider your logic.

If you need those request to get fired on mousemove, you should throttle them. This could look like:

```
$(function() {
    var did_fire = false;

    setInterval(function() {
        if( did_fire ) {
            $.ajax({});
            did_fire = false; 
        }
    }, 2000);

    $(element).mouseover(function() {
       did_fire = true;
    });
});
```

This is a very simple technique to reduce the created requestes to 1/2000ms.

Like always you can go crazy about this and write your own request manager (or use a plugin for that) which stores all the request and fires them in order.

Comment: but this will be continuously running a code even if user doesnt move his mouse ever.

Comment: @Praveen: sure, but seriously a super-thin function call like this every 2 seconds is nothing to worry about. Even on IE4 with a super bad computer this does not affect anything. However, you could start/stop the interval at some point also.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making async = true? What happened? If you get "then dozen of simultaneous requests...what to do with them" who/what in your code is issuing these requests? You will get one response per request.

Think about it: Ajax is pull technology. Ajax push would be great but it doesn't exist.

So make async: true always and thn find out how your code is making dozens of requests.

-- pete

Comment: async:true ... according to jquery specification is by default true and when I removed 'async:false'....dozen of simultaneous request made....

Comment: @Muaz Khan So only send a new request if there is no outstanding/in-flight requests (perhaps consider searching SO for that -- it eixsts -- and or asking a new post; the basic methods include a counter, queue, or shared XHR object, etc). Problem solved. Using non-async *will never work here*.

Comment: @Muaz Khan see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and note the fields exposed on the result of the `ajax` method -- which could be useful to test in-flight status?

Answer (score 0):

although you have accepted **Jonathan Fingland's** answer, it has got some problems

1. Usually twitter or 3rd party app require JSONP as data type(its a constrain because of cross domain request). In jQuery when dataType=JSONP, error function specified in jQuery.ajax is never invoked if any error occurs(for that you can use a plugin). That means if any error occurs on server `active_check` variable  will remain `true` forever.
2. Suppose a user moves his mouse for 50 seconds and ur ajax request end successfully in 10 seconds, that means you are still making  4 or 5 requests with this method

**A better Solution**

```
jQuery(function(){
    var delay=50;
    var handler;
     $(document).bind('mousemove', function(e)
      {
         if (e.pageY > $(document).height() - 400)
           {
              if(handler)
              {
                 clearTimeout(handler);
              }
              else
              {
                 handler= setTimeout(makeAjaxRequest,delay);
              }
            }               

        });
      function makeAjaxRequest()
        {
          $.ajax( {
                    url: '/Tweet/GetFiveUserTweets',
                    type: 'POST',
                    async: true,  
                    success: function ( result )
                    {
                        // do something
                    }
                } );
        }   
 });
```

Comment: Although the delay is a very desirable addition here, I would still do the clearTimeout inside the success callback. Doing so would change the delay from 50 to 50 plus the time for the ajax round-trip. This avoids makings any assumptions about the duration of the ajax request which may vary significantly.